# auto number with select list

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to create autonumber with this structur: RA001

- "R" is default falue
- "A" is generate from select list
- "001" is a autonumber

example: when i select list item "A" field with id="namakolom" is auto fill with value "RA001" but when i select list item "B" field with id="namakolom" is auto fill with "RB001".

sory for my bad english.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Tabel Rak</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="modal fade" id="modalRak" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>x</span></button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="POST" name="tambahkolom" role="form">
                   <h2 class="no-mar"><small>Tabel Rak</small></h2>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="namakolom">Kode Rak</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namakolom" name="namakolom" readonly>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="kodekolom">Kode Kolom</label>
                       <select name="kodekolom" id="kodekolom" class="form-control">
        <option value="" class="disabled selected">Pilih Kode Kolom</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
                                <option value="B">B</option>  
                                </select>
                   </div>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                   <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="tambahkolom">
               </form>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rrak);

mysql_free_result($rkolom);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var defaultValue = 'R'
var autoNumber = '001'    
$('#kodekolom').on('change', function(e) {
 var currentValue = $(this).val()
 $('#namakolom').val(defaultValue + currentValue + autoNumber)
})
</script>
```